# Invalid code snippets in XHTML1.0

Tags: xhtml, xhtml-1.0-strict

Can anyone advise why the following is not valid strict xhtml 1.0?

```
<p align="right"> 

<table align="right"> 

<form name="login" action="/scripts/login.cgi" method="post">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`align` attribute is presentational and replaced by CSS.

Paragraphs may not contain tables.

Forms may not be child nodes of tables.

`name` attribute of forms is removed in favour of `id`.

Comment: Hi Quentin - sorry, I should have been more clear. Each of those are independent statements, so not nested in each other. It is a sample test question where we have to look at each snippet independently, and state why each isn't valid.

Comment: But this is Valid <td align="right"> which I don't understand, because that means align attribute is still valid in some circumstances? And thank you for the name/id pointer.

Comment: You have a test in 2016 about what was made invalid between 1997 and 1999? When XHTML 1.0 Strict is now obsolete too? That's … practical.

Comment: Some presentational stuff got left in because CSS replacements weren't quite there at the time.

Comment: Yeah I know, it's absolutely ridiculous. And it's with a leading university. There are about 60 of us taking it, and none of us have a clue how to even find this information out  - we haven't been taught it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Also, do you know of any way that I could find out where the use of align is valid, and where it isn't?

Comment: XHTML 1 is mostly the same as HTML 4.01 which has a [table that shows which DTD attributes appear in and which are deprecated](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html).

Comment: That is to say, the _elements_ and _attributes_ in XHTML1.0 are the same as in HTML 4.01. Other features differ.